# Gracefully updating server code

Tags: deployment, node.js, upgrade

I have exactly one Node server, which is currently running some code. This code is now outdated. How can I switch to the new code without any server down-time? Do I need to get another server to act as a buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you "kill" the old process and immediately start the server again, read the following article for more details & code sample:

http://codegremlins.com/28/Graceful-restart-without-downtime